# CSS/Jquery fadeIn() function ignoring z-axis

Tags: javascript, html, css

Here is my insert javascript function that is set to an "onHover" event for tool tips on my application.

```
$('.ttip').hover(function () {
            var ttip_c = $(this).data('ttip');
            var ttip_h = $(this).height();
            $(this).append('<div class="ttip_t">' + ttip_c + '</div>');
            $('.ttip_t').css({
                'top': ttip_h + ttip_h / 2,

            });
            $('.ttip_t').fadeIn();
        }, function () {
            $('.ttip_t').fadeOut(function () {
                $(this).remove();
            });
        });
```

The z-axis is set in the ttip class at 9999 and I set the opacity of the element it is supposed to go over as <1, but the element seems to ignore the z-axis property. Any ideas? Here is the css of the ttip element

```
.ttip_t {
position: absolute;
left: 50%;
top: 100%;
background: #6835B1;
display: none;
color: #fff;
font-size: 12px;
text-align: center;
width: 100px;
margin-left: -50px;
border-radius: 3px;
padding: 5px 7px;
z-index: 9999;
line-height: 1.5em;
display: block;
}
```

Here is the css of the element it is supposed to go over.

```
.minicard-container {
position: relative;
flex-wrap: wrap;
overflow: hidden;
padding-top: 5px;
padding-bottom: 50px;
display: flex;
}
```

Any ideas? I think it might be the fadeIn causing some weird effect, but I got rid of it and it still did nothing.

Comment: Can you make a snippet or fiddle of your code including HTML

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. See: How to create a [mcve].

Comment: is the element it's supposed to go over its sibiling?

Comment: Try removing `overflow: hidden;` from `.minicard-container` assuming `.ttip_t` isa child of `.minicard-container`. Otherwise give us a demo so we can see.